# How to combine DTO + non DTO

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm currently creating a new endpoint and I want to check just 2 params (limit and offset) with the dto, and the third param doesn't

I have the following test code in my controller but it is not working as expected, the endpoint returns me a message: "*property startDate should not exist*". What should I do to get the result I want? Or what other options could I use for this case (other than creating a new dto)?

```
@Get()
methodName(
  @Query('startDate') startDate: Date,
  @Query() paginationDto: PaginationDto
) {
  return this.reviewsService.methodName(startDate, paginationDto);
}
```

Comment: I guess, you can achieve it like `@Query() query: PaginationDto & { startDate: Date }`, although I think `Date` won't be a valid type for a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> other than creating a new dto

This is your best option if you're using strict validation from the `ValidationPipe` (i.e. not allowing unknown properties to the DTO). This is because `@Query()` is essentially `req.query` and `@Query('startDate')` is `req.query['startDate']`. Unless you make specific decorators that pull the values off of the original location, like `@PullFromQuery('startDate')` that *gets* the data *and* modifies the `req.query`, something like:

```js
export const PullFromQuery = createParamDecorator((data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  if (data) {
    const retData = req.query[data];
    delete req.query[data];
    return retData;
  }
  return req.query;
})
```

But honestly, I wouldn't modify the `req.query` unless you really need to and would just create the second DTO.